# Enter all the inputs of an array at a time

Tags: python-3.x

```
p=5
a=[]
for in range(p):
 a[i]=int(input().split())
```

I want to give input like

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

All input takes at a time in an array 'a'

what do I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: `a=range(1,6)` gives what you want, no?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question, you want to input a single string like `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` and map it in an integer array like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

You can do it with using `split()` and `map()`:

```
>>> input_str = input()
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>>> '1 2 3 4 5 6 7'

>>> input_list = input_str.split()
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

>>> a = list(map(int, input_list))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

*Explanation:*

- First, you read your string from the buffer
- Then you use the `split()` method to make a list, containing each element of your input string
- To transform this string list into an integer one, you use the combination of `list()` and `map()` -> `list(map(int, input_list))`

*One-liner solution*: `list(map(int, input().split()))`, produces the exact same result.

Comment: You should also encapsulate it with try-except so you can react on invalid data.

Comment: @Wencakisa
Sir my problem is that
I want to display a matrix whose rows and column given by user
and the input format for that matrix is like
3 5
13 4 8 14 1
9 6 3 7 21
5 12 17 9 3⁠⁠⁠⁠